Time Machine backup lost: how to prompt TM to start backup from current state
A previous BigSur TM SSD backup failed and the TM SSD was reformatted.
What must be done to reset TM to its initial state so that it will prompt the user to start a fresh backup starting with today?  The goal is to transfer data files (not applications) to a new Sonoma box.
The UI seems to be stuck here:


You don't need to do anything special. Just select the new volume as a backup destination in the Time Machine settings panel, which if found in Settings => Time Machine.
